# Scoping Protestantism?

Tags: discussion, scope

On this site, we frequently close questions that have far too broad of scopes, and for good reason! Asking 5 Christians one question on the atonement could produce 7 different answers.

Recently, I’m starting to notice questions that get scoped to “Protestantism”. But surely this is far too broad! Protestantism is a wide range of theological traditions and interpretations. So can we allow this scope? Or do we need to require more rigorous scopes?

---

For reference, see [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91336/according-to-protestants-when-did-the-kingdom-of-god-arrive) in which the OP ACKNOWLEDGES the fact that many different viewpoints can answer.

Comment: I think it should be scoped to whatever you think is going to contain the relevant answer. If you think there's going to be an authoritative answer within a scope, but it turns out there isn't, that in itself is informative. But if you already know it's an area of hot debate within a scope, probably it should be either a survey or more specifically scoped.

Answer (score 1):

Each question needs an appropriate scoping. For some questions the appropriate scoping is, for example, all of Trinitarianism, when the question concerns the subject matter of the Trinity itself.

So Protestantism is the appropriate scoping when the question concerns one of the distinctive marks of Protestantism, such as the Solas.

Expertise of subject matters is required to know when a scoping should be narrowed, or even when it would be better to be broadened.

Comment: I like this answer. So just to make sure I’m fully understanding you - the scope of Protestantism should only be used in reference to the 5 solas?

Comment: @LukeHill That's just one example. There's more than just them.

Comment: could you add those to your answer?

Comment: @LukeHill No, sorry. I'm not going to try to make an exhaustive list. There doesn't need to be one.

Comment: no problem. Just trying to clarify when it an appropriate scope.